# Apache L|Last flag not stopping the loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I am rewriting requests for specific page accesses but I would like to add an exclusion to a few pages. Let's say, I would like my request site.com/page/test to goto site.com/page.php?str=test but I want to add an exclusion to one string for not going to that page but to another page, like: site.com/page/contact should go to site.com/contact.php

This is how I am trying:

```
RewriteRule ^static/mobile_app/?$ static/mobile_app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^static/([a-zA-Z0-9%.\-_]+)/?$ static/page.php?url_key=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I also have this at the end of file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? /static/page.php?url_key=404 [L]
```

One strange thing is, if I try the following rule, it works:

```
RewriteRule ^static/mobile_app.php$ static/mobile_app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^static/([a-zA-Z0-9%.\-_]+)/?$ static/page.php?url_key=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Means, if I try to write the complete filename with extension, it works. Could anybody please help? Thanks.

Comment: Try to define your problem clearly as it is not really understandable.

Comment: @anubhava thanks. I have again wrote the description in the last line. Is it understandable now? What I was trying to say was that if i write complete filename in the rule, it works for me. But I want the rule to work without adding .php to my rule.

Comment: @RajaAmerKhan: what is working or not working? I mean what is the url you type in the browser? And where are the rules for `contact`?

Comment: @regilero Rule static/mobile_app.php goes fine to static/mobile_app.php [L]. Whereas, static/mobile_app does not go to static/mobile_app.php [L].

Answer (score 2):

Have your complete `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^static/([\w.-]+)/?$ static/page.php?url_key=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /static/page.php?url_key=404 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks but it's not redirecting it to the requested file. With above code, I tried static/mobile_apps but it did not take me to the static/mobile_apps.php and instead 404 page. I also tried adding rewrite rule: ^static/mobile_apps/?$ static/mobile_apps.php [L] along with your rules but it didn't help.

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: 1. This is the only .htaccess and it's in root (not in static directory). 2. No, there's a lot of code but none of it is related to these rules. Those are also rewrite rules but for other pages. Should I still post it? 3. The last 3 lines you posted are at bottom, the rest of code is beside other rewrite rules.

Comment: also, your code takes static/testpage.php to static/testpage but this is not what I want?

Comment: `static/testpage.php to static/testpage but this is not what I want` Oh I see then I think I didn't understand ALL of your requirements clearly. Can you edit the question and list your requirements in bullet points.

Comment: alright. thanks for your help. I will edit my question today evening as I am working on something else right now. Once again thanks.